# Maven: Build dependencies with dynamic params on persistence.xml file when main project is been compiled

Tags: java, maven, jpa, dependencies

I am a new maven user.

I am developing differents projects that depends on a maven project that needs to connect to db using JPA. So, for each parent project I need to set the db URL, user name and password on persistence.xml on dependent project.

I want to know if there is a way to recompile the dependency setting this values dynamically on persistence.xml while one of parent projects.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need to generate a persistence.xml for each project independently.

You could [Maven Filters](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) to merge the properties defined in pom as well as passed through command line (-D option)

I am not sure about your requirement but you could also create an archetype from which you can create all the child projects.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The problem is that I have 3 or 4 versions of same project that point to JPA project. So, each project connects to differents DBs. What I want to do is automatically re-build the JPA project with corresponding db settings on persistence.xml, when one of those main projects is built.